# Estimating in Python

Tags: python, tail-recursion

I am trying to write a python function which will give me back the first value of a number `k` which will `function 2 >= function 1`

```
function 1(p) => 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/p!
function 2(k) => (1 + 1/k)^k
```

So I input use `2` for example in `function 1`. It would take estimate e at 2.5 but it would take k being 6 for it to get close which is    2.522.

I want to return the 6.

I get this far but I am not sure where to go from there.

```
for x in range(p):
    factorial(x):
        if x == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return x * factorial(x-1)
result = 1 + 1/factorial(p)
```

Comment: `factorial(n):` isn't syntacically correct... What is `x` used for?

Comment: So I can get `1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/n!`

Comment: But you start `factorial(p)`, and never use `x`

Comment: yes should be x. thx for that

Comment: In other words, 1) you did not actually define a function, there is a `def` missing 2) You shouldn't be making a function within a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need two separate functions, and no loops are needed.

```
def factorial(x):
    if x in {0, 1}:
        return 1  # This needs to be 1, otherwise you multiply everything by 0
    else:
        return x * factorial(x-1)

def summ(p):
    if p == 0:
        return 1
    elif p == 1:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1/factorial(p) + summ(p-1)
```

---

Regarding the rest of the question, I think this will help

```
def f2(k):
  return 1 if k == 0 else (1 + 1/k)**k

max_iter = 10  # TODO: increase
k = 0
delta = 0.000001
while max_iter > 0:
  f1_result = summ(k)
  f2_result = f2(k)

  check = f1_result <= f2_result
  print("k={}:  {:6.8f} <= {:6.8f} == {}".format(k, f1_result, f2_result, check))

  k += 1
  max_iter -= 1

  # if check:
  #    break

# TODO: Check if difference is within acceptable delta value
```

Output

```
k=0:  1.00000000 <= 1.00000000 == True
k=1:  2.00000000 <= 2.00000000 == True
k=2:  2.50000000 <= 2.25000000 == False
k=3:  2.66666667 <= 2.37037037 == False
k=4:  2.70833333 <= 2.44140625 == False
k=5:  2.71666667 <= 2.48832000 == False
k=6:  2.71805556 <= 2.52162637 == False
k=7:  2.71825397 <= 2.54649970 == False
k=8:  2.71827877 <= 2.56578451 == False
k=9:  2.71828153 <= 2.58117479 == False
```

From larger numbers, this check still fails at `k=996` and throws a recursion error.

```
k=996:  2.71828183 <= 2.71691848 == False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 22, in <module>
  File "python", line 13, in summ
  File "python", line 5, in factorial
  File "python", line 5, in factorial
  File "python", line 5, in factorial
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Therefore, it would help if you wrote a factorial function using a loop rather than recursion.

---

**Edit**

I think I understand what you are trying to get now

```
in1 = int(input("value 1:"))
v1 = summ(in1)
v2 = 0
max_iter = 50  # Recursion execution limit
while f2(v2) <= v1 and max_iter > 0:
  v2 += 1
  max_iter -= 1
print(v2)
```

Output

```
value 1: <enter 2>
6
```